# Django and Tastypie, overwrite a specific field in a OnToMany field

Tags: python, django, tastypie

We have an old version of a mobile app that crashes if it can't match a field.  Its on an early version of an API -- so all I have to is override the single usage in the API to a safe value for the older apps.  (I can't change the value in the database for the newer apps).

I figured out to use dehydrate and set the value correctly after much research.  The value in my console is being changed -- however, browser output doesn't pick up the change.  I'm a bit stumped.

Here's the full model resource.    Please excuse my python - while I'm a huge fan - its not my normal stomping ground.

```
class SectionResource(ModelResource):

   articles = fields.ToManyField('app.api.ArticleResource', "articles_sections", null=True, full=True)

   class Meta:
       queryset = Section.objects.all()
       resource_name = "sections"
       filtering = {
           'id': ['exact'],
       }

   def dehydrate(self, bundle):

        for i in range(len(bundle.data['articles'])):

            if bundle.data['articles'][i].obj.template == "Program":

                 bundle.data['articles'][i].obj.template = "Template"

                 #print bundle.data['articles'][i].obj.template #updated in print but not browser

        return bundle
```

Comment: What is the obj property of the article? Can you please post the ArticleResource? Can this be a cache problem in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed printing the same thing you are assigning, but does article has an obj property to be serialized ?

Your version with proposed fix:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):

    for i in range(len(bundle.data['articles'])):

        if bundle.data['articles'][i]["template"] == "Program":

             bundle.data['articles'][i]["template"] = "Template"

    return bundle
```

Fixed rewrited version:

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):

    for article in filter(lambda a: a.get("template") == "Program", bundle.data.get('articles', [])):
        article["template"] = "Template"

    return bundle
```